# Meteor: Fire Event on Browser Back Button

Tags: meteor

I am using Meteor.JS and want to fire an event (Animating the Closing of a modal) when the user hits the Browser's Back button and want to avoid in some cases, that the back default behaviour happens (so only close modal, do not change page, at second click change page)

Comment: just listen for route changes. i dont think there is a event for the back button. and if there is please comment it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using [history.pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) to change the URL bar when your modal appears, so that going Back does the right thing. A library like backbone.js or a Meteor package like iron:router can help with this.

Comment: we are using iron:router for main site navigation, but as we do not want that the base-url changes for some modals (e.g. a "This Feature is not available" or "You need to login to use this feature do you want to go to the login page"), we cannot add new routes for that. Probably there is a posibility to change only the hash-part or the uri and react to that.